# keyboard shortcut in mail not working

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, shortcut

I have set a keyboard shortcut `command + L-shift + R-arrow` for moving the selected mail to a particular folder. However, it doesn't work (apart from giving the invalid keystroke sound).

> However, I observed a very peculiar behaviour i.e. If I go to the
>   `Message > Move To` (and do not click anything), the shortcut starts
>   working.

To shed more light on this weird problem that I am facing, please watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-s2uM4SVWE&feature=youtu.be). In this video, I try to use the shortcut but it doesn't work. However, if I do the steps as shown, the shortcut starts working.

**Therefore, I wanted to know why the keyboard shortcut is not working (at first) and why it starts working after that.**

Comment: Pure guess - it doesn't build the list until the first time you open the menu, so the command simply doesn't exist until then.

Comment: I guess so but we hardly do this for every shortcut that we create.